# How to make combination matrix in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some names:

```
ID NAME
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

I want to insert them as a matrix:

```
ID NAME1 NAME2
     A     B
     A     C
     A     D
     B     C
     B     D
     C     D
```

so `NAME1 <> NAME2` and a combination may occur only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Name
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.Name < t2.Name
ORDER BY t1.Name, t2.Name
```

The idea is to perform a self-join with all *subsequent* rows.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aadfa/2)

Comment: Like your better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try that too:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name FROM table_name t1
LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.name != t2.name AND t1.ID < t2.ID
WHERE t2.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.name ASC, t2.name ASC;
```

[SQLFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55ffff/2)